# Unidentified Resource by the URI

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Making a WPF UI, have a Grid, some rows and textblocks. 
Heres the CS for the XAMl;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Xaml;
using Microsoft;
using Microsoft.Expression;
using Microsoft.Expression.Utility.ValueEditors;
using IGotThis;

namespace Project1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            String[,] outlookArray = IGotThis.PullOutLookMessages.getOutlookMessages();
            this.OutLookInfo.DataContext = outlookArray;
        }
    }
```

IGotThis is another CS, which i believe to be unrelated. 
Whenever i debug the program, my WPF designer page gets replaced with this:

> Exception: The component 'Microsoft.Expression.Utility.ValueEditors.SplitComboBox' does not have a resource identified by the URI '/Microsoft.Expression.Utility;component/valueeditors/splitcombobox.xaml'.
>
> StackTrace
>
> at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
>   InnerException: None.

I don't understand this error in the slightest. In my xaml code, 
`UserControl` is underlined with a blue worm withe the same error.

Edit: Heres my XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project1.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" Width="528" Height="556.4">
<Grid x:Name="OutLookInfo">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="98"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="69*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="139*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="93*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="255*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Sender Name"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="0,23,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="98" FontSize="16" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Text="CC'd People"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="0,59,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="98" FontSize="16" TextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Subject"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="0,39,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="98" FontSize="16" TextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Body Text"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="0,112,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="98" FontSize="16" TextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="3"/>
    <TextBlock Text ="{Binding outlookArray}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="235" Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.Row="3" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="410"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="71" Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="410" FontSize="18"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="119" Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="410" FontSize="18"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="49" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="410" FontSize="18"/>
</Grid>
```

I'm not sure if this is related, but i just found this warning in my errors list:

```
Warning 1   There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "Microsoft.Expression.Utility, Version=5.0.30709.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=x86", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.  IGotThis
```

I'm not sure what it means, or how to change the "targeted processor architecture"

Comment: It looks like a component you're using references an assembly -- try adding a reference to `Microsoft.Expression.Utility.dll`?

Comment: Where would that be located? I looked through each tab in the Add Reference, it wasn't located there, and if i tried to do a using statement, it gives me an no reference error.

Comment: Did a manual search, found the .dll files with Microsoft.Expression.Utility, but upon adding it told me that they were already referenced.

Comment: @CameronMeyer, please include which framework version you are working with

Comment: Could you give us the `XAML` in question? I want to see what, how and where `OutLookInfo` is defined on your `UserControl`'s `XAML`, but post as much as you can if it's not overly spammy.

Comment: Forgive the inline styling, I just started working with WPF and don't know the conventions yet.

Comment: I have a suspicion that it might have something to do with the `IGotThis.cs` file. From the exception I gather that somewhere a `URI` is defined with the path specified in the exception, and seeing as you do not apparently define it in the `UserControl` it could be defined somewhere in a supporting file/library/control that you are using to get outlook messages.

And on an unrelated topic, your 5th `TextBlock`'s binding will not work, `outlookArray` is just the name of the variable you used when assigning the `DataContext`, just use `{Binding}` to bind to the `DataContext` as is.

Comment: The only thing that could have an uri (don't know a whole lot about connectiosn yet) is the outlook connection. IGotThis just connects to my outlook account and pulls every item in the inbox. And thanks for the binding tip.

Comment: Also, only my xaml.cs uses the reference Microsoft.Expression.

Comment: I encountered same error when I included Mahapps.metro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. I think it may have to do that i was attempting to run the WPF in a console application. I switched over, and now don't get any errors.

Comment: Please elaborate. How you did it?