# How to resolve the Exception: The component 'Microsoft.Expression.Utility.ValueEditors.SplitComboBox'

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am creating a user control in WPF Application. But now there is an
**Exception: The component 'Microsoft.Expression.Utility.ValueEditors.SplitComboBox' does not have a resource identified by the URI '/Microsoft.Expression.Utility;component/valueeditors/splitcombobox.xaml'.**

i tried adding the **Microsoft.Expression.Utility dll** but still it is showing the same error. As I am new to WPF, i could not find the source to this error. Please provide me some input.

Many Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

May you are try to create a console application. Can you check it and follow this link;

[Unidentified Resource by the URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754241/unidentified-resource-by-the-uri)

Comment: I have created an application of type WPF Application(.Net Framework 4.5).

Comment: How to check whether i am attempting to run the WPF in a console application?

Comment: Just take a look at wheather your solution start app is a console app or not. You can control it via solution properties.