# WPF .xaml designer exception

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, mahapps.metro

I am developing WPF Desktop app and I am getting this error on my xaml designer preview. I have gone through many links but not able to figure out.

The same question was also raised before it. [Unidentified Resource by the URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754241/unidentified-resource-by-the-uri) however I am still unable to resolve it. I have also attached images below.

[image]

Here is the complete error:

```
Exception: The component 'Microsoft.Expression.Utility.ValueEditors.SplitComboBox' does not have a resource identified by the URI '/Microsoft.Expression.Utility;component/valueeditors/splitcombobox.xaml'.
```

And also, I am facing the warning message.
[image]

```
Warning 7   There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the   project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "Microsoft.Expression.Utility, Version=5.0.30709.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=x86", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.    Predictions Version 1
```

To resolve above warning, I gone through this [link](http://blog.amastaneh.com/2012/10/mismatch-between-processor-architecture.html) but all in vain.

Program runs fine, but I need to implement design changes and to observe the change, I have to run program again and again as design preview is not working.

Also note that, it starts happening when I included **mahapps.metro** library.
I can paste my **.xaml** file if needed. I am using VS2012.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, removing references below solved the problem.
I don't know which one caused the exception though.

- Microsoft.Expression.Blend
- Microsoft.Expression.Interactions
- System.Windows.Interactivity

Comment: I'm not sure if it's still possible in your case to recreate, but is there any way you could narrow down which reference caused the exception?

Comment: for me, the Microsoft.Expression.Utility reference was the cause of this problem.